# EasyOCR inconsistent in recognizing numbers

Tags: python, image-processing, ocr, easyocr

I'm using EasyOCR to extract numbers in image below:

[image]

However, I found that the library is inconsistent in recognizing the numbers. Why does this happen and how to fix?

This is the `readtext` of the program:

```
results = reader.readtext(img, detail=1, paragraph=False, width_ths=1.0)
```

Also here is the original image:

[image]